# Can't load xml data in container view

Tags: ios, xml, swift, xml-parsing, iteration

I'm trying to parse a XML url using XMLParser. Here is the example file:

```
<itemlist>
<item name="Wave" id="1345" working="YES" extra="abcdef"/>
<item name="SCOOP" id="7585" working="YES" extra="sdgsdga"/>
<item name="Alpha" id="3983" working="NO" extra="jkbk"/>
<item name="panda" id="0237" working="YES" extra="adjkbvd"/>
<item name="ANT" id="7483" working="NO" extra="lnvdnlvs"/>
<item name="Wave!" id="9283" working="YES" extra="hiofenl"/>
<item name="o8" id="9473" working="NO" extra="lacknl"/>
<item name="Enjoy" id="8503" working="NO" extra="dnlk"/>
<item name="89" id="8383" working="YES" extra="nklvdnl"/>
<item name="Hub" id="0023" working="NO" extra="vdnlk"/>
</itemlist>
```

I am able to parse the XML file and can see the data in console but only one cell loads on the container view. Here is my code:

```
func beginParsing() {

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/") else { return }

    let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: url)
    parser?.delegate = self
    parser?.parse()
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {

    self.items = [Items]()

    if elementName == "item" {
        let item = Items()
        if let name = attributeDict["name"] {
            item.nameLabel = name
            print(item)
        }
        if let itemWorking = attributeDict["working"] {
            item.itemWorkingLabel = itemWorking
            print(itemWorking)
        }
        if let itemId = attributeDict["id"] {
            item.idLabel = itemId
            print(itemId)
        }
        if let itemExtra = attributeDict["extra"] {
            item.extraLabel = itemExtra
            print(itemExtra)
        }

        self.items?.append(item)
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    self.foundCharacters += string
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "item" {
        let item1 = Item()
        self.items?.append(item1)
        self.items?.removeLast()
    }
    self.foundCharacters = ""
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: Error) {
    print("failure: ", parseError)
}
```

And here is what simulator shows:
[simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYLLY.png)

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is reinit `self.items = [Items]()` on each element parsed (on `didStartElement`).

Also you are removing just added item next line:

```
    self.items?.append(item1)
    self.items?.removeLast()
```

Comment: removing .removeLast() just adds a blank cell in the container view.

Comment: Because let item1 = Item() has no defined fields. You just adding empty item to self.items

Comment: So how can i fix it? Do I have to add all the cells like this?

Comment: Line `func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {` is called each time when new parsed element detected. In this function you create new `[Items]` array and assign it to variable `self.item`. So when parsing is finished, you will have only last element in array. You should move `self.items = [Items]()` out of scope.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I tried that but after removing `self.items = [Items]()` from `didStartElement`, it just shows a blank view with no cells.

Comment: you should move it out of scope, not remove at all. For example move it to `beginParsing()` before `let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: url)`

Comment: Wow! Finally! I can see the data loading. :D Thank you so much, Nikolay!